# How to assert 2 directories are identical in PHPunit?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have 2 directories, multiple files, basically text formats.

- They should be equal.
- I need to know what files are missing/extra (diff will).

What method should I use?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## 2020 Open-Source Package Answer

PHPUnit is still missing this feature, and we needed it to simplify generator tests. So we made a small package [symplify/easy-testing](https://github.com/symplify/easy-testing) that covers it.

The package:

- compares files by their relivate name
- compares their content

### 1. Install

```
composer require symplify/easy-testing --dev
```

### 2. Use

Add `DirectoryAssertableTrait` trait to your test case and use like this:

```php
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Symplify\EasyTesting\PHPUnit\Behavior\DirectoryAssertableTrait;

final class SomeTest extends TestCase
{
    use DirectoryAssertableTrait;

    public function testSuccess(): void
    {
        $this->assertDirectoryEquals(__DIR__ . '/first_directory', __DIR__ . '/second_directory');
    }
}
```